# IE username/password prompt not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, wsh

I'm trying to build a username/password prompt popup using Internet Explorer, but I'm doing something wrong.  When I click on the Username field, the cursor almost always immediately jumps back to the Password field, and when I try to open the dropdown list of servers, again the cursor almost always immediately jumps back to the Password field.  My Javascript code is below.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var Version = "1.0";
var True = 1;
var False = 0;

var aryServers;
var intI, intLen;
var objWShell, objIE;
var strServer, strLoginID, strPassword, strLocalUser, strDefaultServer;
var blnPwdBoxWait;

aryServers = Array( "server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5" );

objWShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
strLocalUser = objWShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" );

blnPwdBoxWait = "";
strLoginID = "";
strPassword = "";
strDefaultServer = "server2";
if ( strPassword == "" ) {
    strPassword = PasswordBox ( "Login_Box_Demo Version " + Version );
    WScript.Sleep( 500 );
}

WScript.Echo( "LoginID: ", strLoginID, ", Password: ", strPassword, ", Server: ", strServer );

objWShell = null;
WScript.Quit( 0 );

// ===========================================================================

function keyHit(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        blnPwdBoxWait = 'DONE';
    }
    return;
}

function PasswordBox( strIETitle ) {
    objIE = new ActiveXObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" );
    objIE.FullScreen = False;
    objIE.AddressBar = False;
    objIE.MenuBar = False;
    objIE.StatusBar = False;
    objIE.ToolBar = False;
    objIE.RegisterAsDropTarget = False;
    objIE.Navigate("about:blank");
    strLoginID = strLocalUser;

    do {
        WScript.Sleep( 100 );
    } while ( ! objIE.ReadyState == 4 );

    objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 300 + 70 );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.resizeTo( 400, 200 + 70 );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.moveTo(
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.width / 2 - 200,
        objIE.document.parentWindow.screen.height / 2 - 200 );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<html>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<title>" + strIETitle + "</title>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "<style type='text/css'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<!--" );
    objIE.document.writeln( ".fixed { font-family:courier new, monospace }" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "-->" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</style>" );

    objIE.document.writeln( "</head>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<body bgcolor=Silver>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<b>" + strIETitle + "</b><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<tr><td colspan=2 align=left>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Enter your username and password:<br>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Username:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input id='userid' size=20 class='fixed' " +
        "value='" + strLoginID + "'>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Password:&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='password' id='passwd' size=20 class='fixed'><p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr><tr><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "Remote Host:&nbsp;&nbsp;" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td><td valign=top>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<select id='server'><br>" );
    intLen = aryServers.length;
    for ( intI = 0; intI < intLen; intI++ ) {
        if ( strDefaultServer == aryServers[ intI ] ) {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "' selected>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        } else {
            objIE.document.writeln( "<option value='" + aryServers[ intI ] +
                "'>" + aryServers[ intI ] + "<br>" );
        }
    }
    objIE.document.writeln( "</select>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</td></tr>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</table>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<p>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='button' value='Submit' id='but0' " +
        "onclick=\"submitted.value='DONE';\">" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "<input type='hidden' id='submitted' value=''>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</form>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</center>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</body>" );
    objIE.document.writeln( "</html>" );
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.scroll="no";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderStyle = "outset";
    objIE.document.parentWindow.document.body.style.borderWidth = "3px";
    objIE.Visible = True;
    objIE.document.addEventListener( "keydown", keyHit, false );

    objWShell.AppActivate( strIETitle );

    blnPwdBoxWait = '';
    try {
        do {
            objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).focus();
            WScript.Sleep( 100 );
            if ( objIE.Visible && blnPwdBoxWait == '' ) {
                blnPwdBoxWait = objIE.document.getElementById( "submitted" ).value;
            }
        } while ( blnPwdBoxWait == '' );
    } catch( err ) {
        WScript.Echo('ERROR: ' + err.message);
        blnPwdBoxWait = 'DONE';
    }
    strLoginID = objIE.document.getElementById( "userid" ).value;
    strPassword = objIE.document.getElementById( "passwd" ).value;
    strServer = objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).options( objIE.document.getElementById( "server" ).selectedIndex ).text;
    objIE.Visible = False;
    objIE.Quit();
    objIE = null;

    return strPassword;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by moving the .focus() statement outside of the do while loop.  Apparently the focus was being forced back to the password input field every time the code looped.